# VSCode hide dotfiles in Remote Open Folder dialog

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using the remote development pack for vscode, I use the "Open Folder" button from the explorer to open a folder on the remote. The dialog that pops up shows a ton of dotfiles on the remote. Is there a way to make the Open Folder dialog not show hidden files? The "files.exclude" property seems to have no effect.